# This is my attempt at having a user input a value into an array. Then to covert it to an amount of asterisks printed

Tags: c++, arrays, string

However when trying to assign a user value to the array of stars to then print an asterisks for each 1000 people this was what i came up with and seem to be getting an error when attempting to assign in this fashion. I am only a few weeks into C++ programming, working in industrial maintenance my main source of programming knowledge comes from PLC's. Is there any tips for assigning values to an array in this fashion.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int pop[5], stars[5];
string out[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

int main()
{
    cout << "\n\t\tPlease enter the population of 4 cities:";
    cout << "\n\t\tPopulation of city 1: "; cin >> pop[1];
    cout << "\n\t\tPopulation of city 2: "; cin >> pop[2];
    cout << "\n\t\tPopulation of city 3: "; cin >> pop[3];
    cout << "\n\t\tPopulation of city 4: "; cin >> pop[4];
    stars[1] = pop[1] / 1000, stars[2] = pop[2] / 1000, stars[3] = pop[3] / 1000, stars[4] = pop[4], out[1].assign(stars[1], "*"), out[2].assign(stars[2], "*"), out[3].assign(stars[3], "*"), out[4].assign(stars[4], "*");
    cout << "\n\n\tCity 1: " << out[1];
    cout << "\n\tCity 1: " << out[2];
    cout << "\n\tCity 1: " << out[3];
    cout << "\n\tCity 1: " << out[4];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question: arrays in c++ are 0-indexed. `int pop[5]` automatically creates space for 5 integers. By indexing only 1-4 you're missing out on the first int in your array. You can declare `int pop[4]` and access it by `pop[0]`, `pop[1]`, etc.

Comment: If you're looking for code review (if this is working as intended), consider posting this to [codereview.se]

Comment: Thank you for the information you’ve provided, related or not, certainly helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, separate your assignments by a semicolon and use one line each.

```
stars[1] = pop[1] / 1000;
stars[2] = pop[2] / 1000;
// ...
```

You should use characters (`char`) and not c-strings (`char*`) as the second argument to `std::string::assign`:

```
out[1].assign(stars[1], '*') // correct
out[1].assign(stars[1], "*") // wrong
```

Comment: I cannot, well actually can, believe that i mistook the " for ' . 

additionally regarding the formatting that was sloppy my apologies..